# Does it invalidate prayer to read it fast?

Tags: salat

In prayer is it okay if you are in a rush, and read quickly in my head? If the last letter of a word and the first letter of another word overlap one another, even if you know you are saying everything, is it okay? It happens unintentionally but I know I am saying everything. Is this makruh or does it invalidate prayer?

*Note: Makruh means it is not haram (and is not sin), but it is better not to do ...*

Comment: Purpose of prayer is to remember Allah.  If you're in a rush just to finish your prayers,  then you have a problem and prayer could be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah,

> Does it invalidate prayer to read it fast?

If reading fast makes you not articulating the letters properly and/or changes the meaning of the verses that you are reciting, then your prayer will be invalid. If the meaning is not changed, then the prayer is valid; however, you don't get any reward from that prayer **except for the amount of time you were actually having Khushu' خشوع (concentration) in that prayer**.

Also, do your best to get rid of that habit because that, praying fast, is one of the attributes of the hypocrites (Munafiqeen). The Prophet (PBUH) said (the hadith is in Sahih Muslim):

> That is the prayer of the munafiq. He waits until the sun is between
>   the horns of the Shaytan (just before sunset), then he pecks four
>   times, and he does not remember Allah, except a little.

Allah knows best!